# How to solve 'Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream.' for Hystrix with Spring Boot 2.3.12 and Java 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am making an application using Spring Boot 2.3.12, Java 11 and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR11. I added Eureka and Hystrix services. When I call 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream' I get a stream of messages like `data: {"type": "ping"}`.

But when I insert this path into 'http://localhost:9195/hystrix/' I get an error message 'Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream.' and WARN-log *'Origin parameter: http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream is not in the allowed list of proxy host names. If it should be allowed add it to hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList'*.

I added this to gateway properties.yaml:

```java
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream, info, health

hystrix:
  dashboard:
    proxy-stream-allow-list: "*"
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```

[image: EUREKA]

[image: HYSTRIX]

**Additional info:**

1. I added `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to pom.xml of gateway-service. I also added `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j`.
2. IntelliJ IDEA marked `proxy-stream-allow-list` and `timeoutInMilliseconds` as *'Cannot resolve configuration property'*
3. These links didn't help: [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream in hystrix dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177728/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard), [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream for Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792290/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-for-hystrix-dashboard-with-spring-clo), [Hystrix: Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300418/hystrix-unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream), [Hystrix Dashboard Issue in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752946/hystrix-dashboard-issue-in-spring-boot), [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream. in Hystrix Dashboard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue).

**UPDATE 1:**
[image: unresolved dependency]

**UPDATE 2:**

I use Hystrix Dashboard as separate new Java module. This module contains application.properties:

```
server.port=9195
```

And main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.EnableHystrixDashboard;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class HystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: That works in my test. What project has the hystrix dashboard dependency? Idea will never resolve most hystrix.* properties. Can you check the value of `hystrix.dashboard.proxy-stream-allow-list` in /actuator/configprops?

Comment: @spencergibb, I added configprops to `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` and opened the webpage on url http://localhost:8080/actuator/configprops, but I do not see `proxy-stream-allow-list` field. Please, check update screen in Q.

Comment: Then the problem is it isn't configured correctly. You never answered which project has the dashboard dependency.

Comment: @spencergibb I create new module for dashboard called hystrix-dashboard.

Comment: And what does that projects application.yml look like?

Comment: Module 'hystrix-dashboard' has only server.port property in application.properties. It starts on port 9195. I updated a question.

Comment: Put `hystrix.dashboard.proxy-stream-allow-list` configuration in that project

Answer (score 0):

modfiy application.yml

```yaml
  management:
    endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: hystrix.stream
      endpoint:
        hystrix:
          stream:
            enabled: true
    hystrix:
      dashboard:
        proxy-stream-allow-list: 127.0.0.1,1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Add an explanation of the configuration, please.